# Why does pytest sometimes report two dicts as unequal?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, pytest

## The Problem

I have a comparison between two dictionaries, say `d1` and `d2`, that look something like this:

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Foo',
    'data': [
        OrderedDict(('name', 'bar'), ('id', 3)),
    ],
}
```

When I assert that these two dictionaries are equal, the assertion sometimes fails. What gets me is that the following code passes:

```
for key in d1.keys():
    assert d1[key] == d2[key]
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this happens, and why it occurs seemingly at random?

---

#### Possible Causes

What I'm really trying to do here is test the output of a serializer from Django Rest Framework. That data is not always returned as a plain dictionary, but other tests against non-nested output work as expected.

I also considered that the assertion might be failing to test the nested list, but the following passes without error:

```
d3 = {'data': d1['data']}
d4 = {'data': d2['data']}
assert d3 == d4
```

#### Example

I have two models, `Foo` and `Bar`. Each `Bar` is owned by a `Foo`. I have the following serializers:

```
class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        model = Bar

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bars = BarSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'bars')
        model = Foo
```

I am trying to unit test the output of `FooSerializer` with the following test:

```
# Assume my_foo_instance is an instance of Foo with one associated Bar
# instance. This should avoid any problems with the ordering of BarSerializer
# affecting the outcome.
serializer = FooSerializer(my_foo_instance)
bar_serializer = BarSerializer(my_foo_instance.bars.all(), many=True)

expected = {
    'id': my_foo_instance.id,
    'name': my_foo_instance.name,
    'bars': bar_serializer.data,
}

assert serializer.data == expected
```

As I said above, the assertion *sometimes* fails.

Comment: Could you provide an example failing case? Also, what output are you testing? Validated data, response content or something else?

Comment: This is most likely because **you think** that both `d1` and `d2` are dicts while one of them is dict-like object.

Comment: This question is missing a **complete** example, [like this (showing that with the mentioned dict it's not a problem)](https://ideone.com/6opA1R). Refer to the [stackoverflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information on how to create one.

Comment: @Hamish, I've added a specific example.

Comment: I now believe that my example was not good enough. With the answer I posted in mind, what is the correct procedure here? Delete the question? Add additional info to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I didn't provide enough context to answer this question. The serializer I was testing inherited from another serializer, so instead of manually constructing all the fields in the test, I pulled in the fields from the base serializer, and then updated that data with the additional expected content like so:

```
base_serializer = BaseFooSerializer(foo)

additional = {
    'more': 'attributes',
    'of': 'foos',
}

expected = base_serializer.data.copy()
expected.update(additional)

assert foo_serializer.data == expected
```

Because DRF serializers don't return a standard Python dictionary, I think the comparison was going wonky. To fix it, I made the following correction:

```
expected = dict(base_serializer.data.items())
```

And now it works fine.

Comment: Nice one. Yeah it returns an `OrderedDict` so this would work.